# Performance issue C++ - searching through an array

Tags: c++, performance

I have two versions of searching through an int array for a specific value.

The first version is the straight forward one

```
int FindWithoutBlock(int * Arr, int ArrLen, int Val)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < ArrLen; i++ )
        if ( Arr[i] == Val )
          return i;
 return ArrLen;
}
```

The second version should be faster. The passed array needs to be one element larger than in the previous case. Say for an array with 5 values, you allocate six ints and then do the following

```
int FindWithBlock(int * Arr, int LastCellIndex, int Val)
{
    Arr[LastCellIndex]  = Val;

    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; Arr[i] != Val; i++ );
    return i;
}
```

this version should be faster - you don't need to check array boundaries with each iteration through Arr.

Now the "issue". When running these functions 100K times on an array of 100K elements in Debug, the second version is roughly 2x faster. In Release however, the first version is approximately 6000x faster. And the question is why.

A program that demonstrates this is to be found at http://eubie.sweb.cz/main.cpp

Any insight is much appreciated.
Daniel

Comment: What compiler and platform are you using?

Comment: I get the following results. DEBUG: Without block: 28.9695
With block: 25.0184 RELEASE: Without block: 7.27841
With block: 5.68094 (Apple LLVM 3.1)

Comment: I know that's not the point here, but at least an honorable mention for [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Comment: I do not see the same result as you do: when I compile with `g++ -O3`, the first is roughly 20% slower than the second.

Comment: well in debug optimization is normally off, in release its on. your first method is static so the compiler can aggressively optimize it, your second is dynamic and thus less optimized by the compiler.

Comment: Just thinking loud. The **first for** has 2 relational operation & the **second for** has 1.

Comment: OP, are you using same compiler flags on test & release?

Comment: `std::find` not good enough?]

Comment: Try assigning, say, 99000 to `SearchVal`. Will the effect still hold?

Comment: I really enjoyed finding the answer to this! +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are my results using DevStudio 2005:

Debug:

- Without block: 25.109
- With block: 19.703

Release:

- Without block: 0
- With block: 6.046

It is very important to run this from the command line and not from within DevStudio, DevStudio does something to affect the performance of the app.

The only way to know what's really happening is to look at the assembler code. Here's the assembler generated in release:-

```
FindWithoutBlock:
00401000  xor         eax,eax 
00401002  cmp         dword ptr [ecx+eax*4],0F4240h 
00401009  je          FindWithoutBlock+1Ah (40101Ah) 
0040100B  add         eax,1 
0040100E  cmp         eax,186A0h 
00401013  jl          FindWithoutBlock+2 (401002h) 
00401015  mov         eax,186A0h 
0040101A  ret
```

Note that the compiler has removed the ArrLen parameter and replaced it with a constant! It has also kept it as a function.

Here's what the compiler did with the other function (FindWithBlock):-

```
004010E0  mov         dword ptr [esp+38h],186A0h 
004010E8  mov         ebx,0F4240h 
004010ED  mov         dword ptr [esi+61A80h],ebx 
004010F3  xor         eax,eax 
004010F5  cmp         dword ptr [esi],ebx 
004010F7  je          main+0EFh (40110Fh) 
004010F9  lea         esp,[esp] 
00401100  add         eax,1 
00401103  cmp         dword ptr [esi+eax*4],ebx 
00401106  jne         main+0E0h (401100h) 
00401108  cmp         eax,186A0h 
0040110D  je          main+0F5h (401115h) 
0040110F  call        dword ptr [__imp__getchar (4020D0h)] 
00401115  sub         dword ptr [esp+38h],1 
0040111A  jne         main+0CDh (4010EDh)
```

Here, the function has been in-lined. The `lea esp,[esp]` is just a 7 byte nop to align the next instruction. The code checks index 0 separately to all the other indices but the main loop is definately tighter than the FindWithoutBlock version.

Hmmm. Here's the code that calls FindWithoutBlock:-

```
0040106F  mov         ecx,edi 
00401071  mov         ebx,eax 
00401073  call        FindWithoutBlock (401000h) 
00401078  mov         ebp,eax 
0040107A  mov         edi,186A0h 
0040107F  cmp         ebp,186A0h 
00401085  je          main+6Dh (40108Dh) 
00401087  call        dword ptr [__imp__getchar (4020D0h)] 
0040108D  sub         edi,1 
00401090  jne         main+5Fh (40107Fh)
```

Aha! The FindWitoutBlock function is only being called once! The compiler has spotted that the function will return the same value every time and has optimised it to a single call. In the FindWithBlock, the compiler can't make the same assumption because you write to the array before the search, thus the array is (potentially) different for each call.

To test this, add the `volatile` keyword like this:-

```
int FindWithoutBlock(volatile int * Arr, int ArrLen, int Val)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < ArrLen; i++ )
        if ( Arr[i] == Val )
            return i;

    return ArrLen;
}

int FindWithBlock(volatile int * Arr, int LastCellIndex, int Val)
{
    Arr[LastCellIndex]  = Val;

    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; Arr[i] != Val; i++ );

    return i;
}
```

Doing this, both versions run in similar time (6.040). Seeing as the memory access is a major bottleneck, the more complex tests of the FindWithoutBlock don't impact on the overall speed.

Comment: One does have to wonder why the compiler, having spotted that the FindWithoutBlock returns the same value every time, goes on to test the return value with a constant REPCOUNT times!

Comment: Skizz, thank you. However, how can the compiler know that ARRLEN is going to be returned each time? I mean if Val was 5 then ARRLEN would not be returned. So to make this kind of optimization the compiler would have to assume that Arr1 has constant content from main and would have to check that SearchVal = 1M is not listed in it. Can such optimization be expected from the compiler?

Comment: @DanielBencik: The compiler doesn't know what the return value will be, just that it is the same value every time (because nothing writes to the array).

Comment: I recently read a good way to write type qualifiers.  Rather than the usual; "volatile int *" write "int volatile *".  Then you can read, verbally, right to left, the type.  Here we have a pointer to volatile int.

Comment: Using `volatile` to fool the optimizer just means your results are irrelevant, not that you've proved anything about the relative function runtimes.

Comment: @DeadMG: As David Hammen states in his answer, the test harness was affecting the results of the test. The volatile was just to show this and that, in the absence of the test harness, there is little difference between the two methods.

Comment: Skizz, exactly. Using volatile, one can see that it was the "constant memory chunk" optimization that was responsible for the difference, not cache missing. As when using the volatile versions, the difference between touching the end of Arr and not touching it is just 0.5s out of a 6.5s runtime. I personally don't see reason for so much fighting about C being bs (as I clearly stated that with C++ you just CANT do these comparisons), however, I want to thank you both for comments.

Answer (score 2):

First, ewwwwww disgusting C garbage. `std::find` and iterators?

But secondly, the compiler's optimizer is written to recognize the first form- not the second. It may be, for example, inlined, unrolled, or vectorized, whereas the second cannot be.

In the general case, consider the cache issue. You are touching the end of the array and then going to the beginning- this could be a cache miss. However in the first block you are cheerily going only sequentially through the array- more cache coherent.

Comment: I thought of the cache miss as well, but that cant be responsible for the huge differences. If inlining is the same thing that the inline  keyword induces then I dont see this causing the speed mismatch. I tried making both functions inline and the results (speeds) are the same. However, Im very low on compiler optimization knowledge, so I will be happy for any new information.

Comment: @Daniel: Why not? Touching an extra cache line unpredictably is pretty damn slow.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Tried setting the block in main as opposed to in the function per se and now both run at the same speed. It is kindof disappointing that halving the operations needed does not produce any speed gains.

Comment: @Daniel: Why? It simply shows that performance is extremely complex and best left to compiler, algorithm, and memory optimizations instead of micro-optimizations. If I were you, I'd be more worried about the fact that both functions were lower quality than what came out of my arse this morning.

Comment: Due to C as opposed to C++? It's not sth I planned to use in real life, I wanted to see the impact of not having to check for the bounds, which I couldnt do with STL.

Comment: @DeadMG: -1 for making assumptions about the compiler and for that comment. Not necessary at all. Nothing wrong with the code. The compiled output is about as good as you'll get from a compiler. Nothing wrong with C either (the whole of the Linux kernel is in C).

Comment: @Skizz: So what? For one, you're assuming that the Linux kernel is of high quality, which you have no evidence to back up. For two, you'd also have to demonstrate that it was developed in a shorter time or with less other costs than would be expected for such software. For three, you would then have to show that this was because of C and not because, say, the engineers involved were above average. C is a worthless pile of garbage and the fact that someone, somewhere, may once have developed one thing with it that might be OK with unspecified costs is irrelevant.

Comment: The important fact is that "pointers as arrays" and "functions which only work on arrays" are both horrendous ideas that should be burned to the ground at the earliest opportunity, along with many other "idioms" which C unfortunately produced, and anyone with access to C++ should be able to do better.

Comment: @DeadMG: So how does one write a C++ program without using any of the features from the "worthless pile of garbage" that is C? Don't forget, you're more likely to find a C compiler for a CPU than a C++ one (if indeed you find a compiler at all).

Comment: @Skizz: With plentiful use of the C++ Standard library- such as, in this case, `std::find`, which unlike the garbage, can operate on many different containers of various types.

Comment: @DeadMG: You use the language that meets the requirement not because it does stuff like operating on containers of different types. I'm currently doing embedded work on VxWorks and I use C++ without any STL since the system can't have exceptions or run-time dynamic allocations. I use C# to write utilities to help develop and test the embedded code because I don't have to mess about with dynamic memory and its GUI framework is sufficient to get the job done. PHP for web programmer. etc. You use the most appropriate tool for the job. If C++ were a hammer, not all problems are nails.

Comment: @Skizz: Very true. But then, the OP did not specify anything like that, and it's the extreme minority, so I'm not too concerned. If you have specific restrictions, then post them in the question- I'm not psychic and can only answer the general case.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer. Skizz already answered the question with "*Aha! The FindWithoutBlock function is only being called once!*"

**Test driver**
I typically tend to put the code for the test driver and the test article in separate files. For one thing, you aren't going to deliver the test driver. For another, combining them like you did lets the optimizer do things you really do not want to be done such as calling the function once rather than 100,000 times. Separating them lets you use different optimization levels for the driver and test article. I tend to compile the driver unoptimized so that the loop that does the same thing 100K times truly is executed 100K times. The test article on the other hand is compiled with the optimization expected for the release.

**Use of getchar()**
It's usually a bad idea to use any I/O inside the test loop when testing for CPU utilization. <strike>Your test code is calling getchar when the item to be found is not in the array.</strike> [Rest of faulty analysis elided.] *Update:* Your test code calls `getchar` when the item to be found is in the array. Even though your test code ensures the item will not be found (and hence `getchar` won't be called) it's still not a good idea to have that call. Do something fast and benign instead.

**C versus C++**
Your code looks more like C± rather than C++. You are using `malloc` rather than `new`, you are intermingling C and C++ I/O, and you aren't using the C++ library such as `std::find`. This is typical for someone moving from C to C++. It's good to be aware of things like `std::find`. This allows you to completely eliminate your `FindWithoutBlock` function.

**Premature optimization**
The only reason to use that `FindWithBlock` formulation is because this search is a bottleneck. So is this truly a bottleneck? The `FindWithoutBlock` formulation (and even better, `std::find`) is arguably a better way to go because you do not need to modify the array and hence the array argument can be marked as `const`. The array cannot be marked as such with `FindWithBlock` because you are modifying the array.

Comment: Oops, getchar is called when the item is in the array. But still, using getchar would produce crazy results if the item was found (since it requires un-prompted user input) so it isn't the best idea in the world.

Comment: Oops, your right. I still don't like the idea of that call being there even if it isn't made. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I observe is that in the first case, the compiler knows at run-time the size of the loop (e.g. < ArrLen).  In the second case, the compiler cannot know.

Comment: There is no compiler at run-time! Also, how does knowing more about the size of the array help? The slow bit is the memory test.

Comment: @Skazz: the compiler can emit code such that different code paths are taken at run-time depending on the size of the array.  If you know the array is small, you can preload the lot into cache and then run the loop.

Comment: @Skizz: you can reduce the number of bounds tested if you unroll the loop. It does not help much though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Looking at what the MS compilers have been producing over the years it seems that loop unrolling is rarely done. This makes sense when you look at the whole system. Back in the 8086 days, loop unrolling helped a lot, but then, memory access wasn't a bottleneck. These days, accessing memory is a bottleneck and that includes reading the code to execute. This means bigger code runs slower, or to put another way, tight loops are faster than unrolled loops. Even doing more branching, the microcode in the CPU does clever stuff to reduce the impact of the conditional branching.

Comment: @BlankXavier: I've never seen the MS compiler prefetch arrays into memory. On modern x86 system, the MMU can automatically prefetch serially accessed data so there is little advantage to prefetching in this scenario. Prefetching has its uses, just not in this code example.

Comment: @Skizz: prefetching stops at page boundaries.  I don't mean crude prefetching in the sense of the C code doing some kind of pre-loading loop.  I mean in a subtler sense, of touching memory (perhaps earlier in the code flow) to guide the prefetcher into doing what you want by the time you need it.

Comment: @BlankXavier: For the data given in the question and the way the data is accessed, the hardware MMU will be significantly more optimal at prefetching the data than using any prefetch instruction.

Comment: @Skazz: the first load will be slow, since the prefetcher doesn't know yet to prefetch.  Why not issue a load for that first element and second element a few hundred cycles prior to entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example there are two conditions checked at every iteration: `i < ArrLen` and `Arr[i] == Val`. In the second example there's only one condition to check. That's why the first loop is twice as slower.

I can't observe the same behavior using GCC: the first loop is still slower.

With `-O0`:

```
Without block: 25.83
With block: 20.35
```

With `-O3`:

```
Without block: 6.33
With block: 4.75
```

I guess that the compiler somehow deduced that there is no `SearchVal` in array and thus there's no reason to call a function which searches for it.

Comment: Huh, that is weird. I use Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7. There is something really fishy going on here, as when I profile the code in VTune I see no time being spent on calling FindWithoutBlock().

Comment: Made my guess as an addition to the answer.

Comment: @Daniel: It's called "inlining".

Answer (score 0):

The first for .. loop contains two conditions for each iteration while the second for loop contains one iteration per loop. For a large number of iterations, this difference should show because there is a RAW dependency between second condition and the iterator increment. But I still don't think that the speedup should be so high.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is smart.

If you use the [LLVM Try Out](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi) page, you will obtain the following IR generated:

```
define i32 @FindWithoutBlock(i32* nocapture %Arr, i32 %ArrLen, i32 %Val) nounwind uwtable readonly

define i32 @FindWithBlock(i32* nocapture %Arr, i32 %ArrLen, i32 %Val) nounwind uwtable
```

The only difference is the presence of the `readonly` attribute on the first function:

From the [Language Reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) page:

> **readonly**
>
> This attribute indicates that the function does not write through any pointer arguments (including byval arguments) or otherwise modify any state (e.g. memory, control registers, etc) visible to caller functions. It may dereference pointer arguments and read state that may be set in the caller. A readonly function always returns the same value (or unwinds an exception identically) when called with the same set of arguments and global state. It cannot unwind an exception by calling the C++ exception throwing methods.

It means that, potentially, the optimizer may realise that the function will always return the same computation (for a given loop) and hoist it outside the loop.